# Getting a better performance on repeatedly method on d3

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

For example, I need to calculate a Math.sqrt of my data for each attr, how can I calculate only one time the Math.sqrt(d)?

```
var circle = svgContainer.data(dataJson).append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d) + 1
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d) + 2
    })
    .attr("rx", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d) + 3
    })
    .attr("ry", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d) + 4
    });
```

Has any elegant/performative mode? I'm thinking this way:

```
var aux;
var circle = svgContainer.data(dataJson).append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        aux = Math.sqrt(d);
        return aux + 1
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return aux + 2
    })
    .attr("rx", function(d) {
        return aux + 3
    })
    .attr("ry", function(d) {
        return aux + 4
    });
```

Comment: write your function  (d) outside and call that function instead of declaring every time.

Comment: You could pre calculate the result in your json and re-use it

Answer (score 2):

An underestimated feature of D3 is the concept of [local variables](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables) which were introduced with version 4. These variables allow you to store information on a node (that is the reason why it is called *local*) independent of the data which might have been bound to that node. You don't have to bloat your data to store additional information.

> D3 locals allow you to define local state independent of data.

Probably the major advantage of using local variables over other approaches is the fact that it smoothly fits into the classic D3 approach; there is no need to introduce another loop whereby keeping the code clean.

Using local variables to just store a pre-calculated value is probably the simplest use case one can imagine. On the other hand, it perfectly illustrates what D3's local variables are all about: [Store](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local_set) some complex information, which might require heavy lifting to create, locally on a node, and [retrieve](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local_get) it for later use further on in your code.

Shamelessly copying over and adapting the code from Gerardo's answer the solution can be implemented like this:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(100, 1000, 100);

var roots = d3.local();   // This is the instance where our square roots will be stored

var ellipses = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("ellipse")
  .attr("fill", "gainsboro")
  .attr("stroke", "darkslateblue")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return roots.set(this, Math.sqrt(d)) * 3;  // Calculate and store the square root
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return roots.get(this) * 3;                // Retrieve the previously stored root
  })
  .attr("rx", function(d) {
    return roots.get(this) + 3;                // Retrieve the previously stored root
  })
  .attr("ry", function(d) {
    return roots.get(this) + 4;                // Retrieve the previously stored root
  });
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but think about something like:     
`var roots = d3.local();
d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
    .x(function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d) }
                                .y(function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d) + 2)`
This doesn't have the variable this inside the function to use the method local.set.

Comment: @ViniciusFolha As @Gerardo already told you in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993342/getting-a-better-performance-on-repeatedly-method-on-d3/45997077?noredirect=1#comment79000810_45993422), this is a completely different question which should be posted as such. In your question you explicitly asked for a solution available in `.attr()`. Both, Gerardo's and my own answer, propose viable solutions for this particular problem. Thus, I will keep this as is and suggest you post another question covering the line generator problem.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. The new question is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185036/getting-a-better-performance-on-repeatedly-method-on-d3-line-generator

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the most idiomatic way for doing this in D3 is using [selection.each](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_each), which:

> Invokes the specified function for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element (nodes[i]).

So, in your case:

```
circle.each(function(d){

    //calculates the value just once for each datum:
    var squareRoot = Math.sqrt(d)

    //now use that value in the DOM element, which is 'this':
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", squareRoot)
        .attr("cy", squareRoot)
        //etc...

    });
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(100, 1000, 100);

var ellipses = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("ellipse")
  .attr("fill", "gainsboro")
  .attr("stroke", "darkslateblue")
  .each(function(d) {
    var squareRoot = Math.sqrt(d);
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return squareRoot * 3
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return squareRoot * 3
      })
      .attr("rx", function(d) {
        return squareRoot + 3
      })
      .attr("ry", function(d) {
        return squareRoot + 4
      });
  })
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Another common approach in D3 codes is setting a new data property in the first `attr` method, and retrieving it latter:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
        //set a new property here
        d.squareRoot = Math.sqrt(d.value);
        return d.squareRoot * 3
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        //retrieve it here
        return d.squareRoot * 3
    })
    //etc...
```

That way you also perform the calculation only once per element.

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.range(100, 1000, 100).map(function(d) {
  return {
    value: d
  }
});

var ellipses = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("ellipse")
  .attr("fill", "gainsboro")
  .attr("stroke", "darkslateblue")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    d.squareRoot = Math.sqrt(d.value);
    return d.squareRoot * 3
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.squareRoot * 3
  })
  .attr("rx", function(d) {
    return d.squareRoot + 3
  })
  .attr("ry", function(d) {
    return d.squareRoot + 4
  });
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

**PS**: by the way, your solution with `var aux` will not work. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what about something like?
`var roots = d3.local();
d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
    .x(function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d) }
                                .y(function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d) + 2)`
I reckon that is not possible to use the each.

Comment: A line generator is different: it's passed an array, and it computes the `x` and `y` positions for each element in that array. Well, saving the computation of one coordinate for the other is an interesting issue... but I'd advise you to post it as **another** question, specifying that you are dealing with a line generator. This current question of yours has already 2 valid answers, and making a different question in the comments is not a god idea here at StackOverflow. So, please, write a new question regarding this new issue.

Comment: Also, you are mistaking me for the other answerer: I'm not the one that proposed using `d3.local()`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. The new question is here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185036/getting-a-better-performance-on-repeatedly-method-on-d3-line-generator