# Getting a better performance on repeatedly method on d3 line generator

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

I've been struggling the past few days to optimize performance on a D3. I'm using a line generator on the SVG and would like to calculate only one time the function used in the `x` and `y`.
For example:

```
d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear) 
  .x(function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d) }
  .y(function(d){ return Math.sqrt(d) + 2) I
```

I would like to save the result of `Math.sqrt(d)` and compute only one time.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  Is just a simple array of numbers?

Comment: I don't understand the practical use of this: if you have the same computation for both `x` and `y` coordinates, you'll have always **just a straight line** going from the top-left corner to somewhere in the SVG. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @TomShanley I just simplified the question, what I'm actually using is Leaflet and converting latitude and longitude to ``x`` and ``y`` layer point. The real fuction is this one :
`d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear).x(function(d){return that.map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x;}).y(function(d){return that.map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y;});` So, it`s a array of LatLng.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result in your first function, and use it in the second

eg

```
d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear) 
  .x(function(d){ 
     d.sqrt = Math.sqrt(d.value);
     return d.sqrt
   })
  .y(function(d){
     return d.sqrt + 2
   })
```